# tkinter Frame grids are not adjusting as per grid config

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

`.gridcolumnconfig` has no effect on output:

I am trying to understand the grid config in tkinter. In the below sample code, the output has no effect for whatever weight I am giving in `.gridcolumnconfig`. Please help me understand how `.gridcolumnconfig` and `.gridrowconfig` work.

thanks in advance

```
    import tkinter

    class Frame_window(tkinter.Frame):
        def __init__(self, p, bg, r=0, c=0, bw=1):
            super().__init__(p)
            self.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='nsew')
            self.config(bg=bg)
            self['borderwidth'] = bw
            self['relief']='sunken'



    root = tkinter.Tk()


    text = f'Welcome to login @page'
    root.title(text)
    root.minsize(480, 240)
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    mainframe = Frame_window(root, 'light yellow')
    mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=2)

    mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
    mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=4)
    mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=4)

    testfram1 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 0, 0, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram1).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram2 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 0, 1, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram2).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram3 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 0, 2, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram3).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram4 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 0, 3, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram4).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram5 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 1, 0, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram5).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram6 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 1, 1, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram6).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram7 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 1, 2, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram7).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram8 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 1, 3, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram8).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram9 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 2, 0, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram9).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram10 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 2, 1, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram10).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram11 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 2, 2, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram11).grid(sticky='nsew')
    testfram12 = Frame_window(root, 'sky blue', 2, 3, 5)
    tkinter.Canvas(testfram12).grid(sticky='nsew')

    root.mainloop()
```

I want the grid layout to adjust in whatever ratio of weights I am providing.

Answer (score 1):

You are associating all of the weights with `mainframe`, but you are putting all of the frames in `root`. The `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` methods only affect the children inside a widget. Since nothing else is in `mainframe`, the weights do nothing.